# Pass data as code

Tags: c++

I'm trying to interpret a formula given as input:

```
y= y argv[1][s] 5;
```

where `argv[1][s]` can be `+ - *` for example.
    y= y+5;
    y= y*5;

I could use a check for specific values, but it's more interesting to find out why this doesn't work.

> error C2146: syntax error : missing
>   ';' before identifier 'argv'

I think what happens is that `+` is passed as `'+'` so no operation results. Is there a way to unquote this?

Comment: Could you add some sample code to clarify the question?

Comment: You should definitely grab a beginner C++ textbook!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, because that's not how C++ works.  Your code must make sense at compile-time, so that the compiler can convert it to a fixed set of assembler instructions.  Run-time text is not "substituted" in; there is no equivalent of "eval" like in some interpreted languages.

If you want to do this, you'll need to do something like:

```
switch (argv[1][s])
{
case '+':
    y = y + 5;
    break;
case '-':
    y = y - 5;
    break;
case '*':
    y = y * 5;
    break;
default:
    std::cerr << "Unrecognised operator: \"" << argv[1][s] << "\"" << std::endl;
    break;
}
```

Comment: +1: but probably the correct word is not "compiled" (Common Lisp is compiled but has eval; also text is not the only possible way to handle code as data - see Lisp macros).

Comment: That's what I meant by a check. Unquoting doesn't have to be literal. Maybe there is some other way to do this. If the processor can perform the command why does it have to be specified in the program and not be part of input?

Comment: @6502: You're right about "compiled".  Can you think of a better term?

Comment: @user: Because that's how C++ works.  Any language that supports an eval-like mechanism will fundamentally be doing something a bit like this under the hood (although obviously it will be running a much more sophisticated parser!).

Comment: @user490735 "If the processor can perform the command..." the processor can't perform the command. The knowledge that the string "+" corresponds to the CPU instruction `add` (or whatever) is part of the C++ compiler, not part of the CPU. This knowledge isn't available at runtime in a compiled C++ program.

Comment: What would be needed to pass instructions as machine code? I.e., program 00192809 where 00192809 is machine code for add a,b. While this is certainly something else, how would I go about specifying what a and b are given that I want it to work with the program's code?